# Spark where to set "spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir" configuration?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I was trying to point location for Spark in order to write log files(using log4j). At spark [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#debugging-your-application) it says in order to logs get collected from yarn I have to set that property. But I couldn't find 'spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir' property neither in spark-default.conf nor in yarn-site.xml. So my questions are;

1-) Where to set this property ?

2-) Is there any default value for it?(In order to be collected by yarn properly)

3-) Can I set it via spark-submit command ?

Comment: in spark-submit as a parameter?

Comment: if you mean setting it as --conf spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir /some_dir at spark submit it is giving error. Error: Invalid argument to --conf: spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir